# Optimize Postgres query on timestamp range

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, database-partitioning, postgresql-performance

I have the following table and indices defined:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
  wid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tickets_id_seq'::regclass),
  eid bigint,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  argsxml text,
  moduleid character varying(255),
  source_id bigint,
  file_type_id bigint,
  file_name character varying(255),
  status_reason character varying(255),
  ...
)
```

I created an index on the `created` timestamp as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX ticket_1_idx
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (created );
```

Here's my query:

```
select * from ticket 
where created between '2012-12-19 00:00:00' and  '2012-12-20 00:00:00'
```

This was working fine until the number of records started to grow (about 5 million) and now it's taking forever to return.

Explain analyze reveals this:

```
Index Scan using ticket_1_idx on ticket  (cost=0.00..10202.64 rows=52543 width=1297) (actual time=0.109..125.704 rows=53340 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((created >= '2012-12-19 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created <= '2012-12-20 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
Total runtime: 175.853 ms
```

So far I've tried setting:

```
random_page_cost = 1.75 
effective_cache_size = 3
```

Also created:

```
create CLUSTER ticket USING ticket_1_idx;
```

Nothing works. What am I doing wrong? Why is it selecting sequential scan? The indexes are supposed to make the query fast. Anything that can be done to optimize it?

Comment: It's not doing a sequential scan. It's doing an index scan.

Comment: Also it's only taking 175ms to run. If it's taking forever, it's likely the OP has a huge dataset that's taking a long time to transfer across the wire, not time to run the query.\

Comment: BTW: `effective_cache_size=3` might be a bit too low. (but probably won't harm in this case)

Comment: Why do you consider 175ms "ages"?

Comment: Don't do a `select *` as it will increase the result set size to be transferred to the client.

Answer (score 32):

#### [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html)

If you intend to use `CLUSTER`, the displayed syntax is invalid.

<strike>`create CLUSTER ticket USING ticket_1_idx;`</strike>

Run once:

```
CLUSTER ticket USING ticket_1_idx;
```

This *can* help a lot with bigger result sets. Less for a single or few rows returned.
If your table isn't read-only the effect deteriorates over time. Re-run `CLUSTER` at reasonable intervals. Postgres remembers the index for subsequent calls, so this works, too:

```
CLUSTER ticket;
```

(But I would rather be explicit and use the first form.)

**However**, if you have lots of updates, `CLUSTER` (or `VACUUM FULL`) may actually be bad for performance. The right amount of bloat allows `UPDATE` to place new row versions on the same data page and avoids the need for extending the underlying physical file (expensively) too often. You can use a carefully tuned `FILLFACTOR` to get the best of both worlds:

- [Fillfactor for a sequential index that is PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187192/fill-factor-for-a-sequential-index-that-is-pk/14187367#14187367)

#### [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/blob/master/doc/pg_repack.rst) / [`pg_squeeze`](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze)

`CLUSTER` takes an exclusive lock on the table, which may be a problem in a multi-user environment. [Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html)

> When a table is being clustered, an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock is acquired
> on it. This prevents any other database operations (both **reads and
> writes**) from operating on the table until the `CLUSTER` is finished.

Bold emphasis mine. Consider the alternatives!

[**`pg_repack`**](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/blob/master/doc/pg_repack.rst):

> Unlike `CLUSTER` and `VACUUM FULL` it works online, without holding an
> exclusive lock on the processed tables during processing. pg_repack is
> efficient to boot, with performance comparable to using `CLUSTER` directly.

and:

> pg_repack needs to take an exclusive lock at the end of the reorganization.

The current version 1.5 works with PostgreSQL 9.4 - 15. There is also a release note claiming: *"Added support for PostgreSQL 16"*.

[**`pg_squeeze`**](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze) is a newer alternative that claims:

> In fact we try to replace [`pg_repack`](https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/) extension.

The current version 1.6 works with Postgres 10 - 16.

#### Query

The query is simple enough not to cause any performance problems per se.

However: The [`BETWEEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) construct *includes* boundaries. Your query selects all of Dec. 19, *plus* records from Dec. 20, 00:00. That's an *extremely unlikely* requirement. Chances are, you really want:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ticket 
WHERE  created >= '2012-12-19 00:00'
AND    created <  '2012-12-20 00:00';
```

#### Performance

> Why is it selecting sequential scan?

Your `EXPLAIN` output clearly shows an *Index Scan*, not a sequential table scan. There must be some kind of misunderstanding.

You may be able to improve performance, but the necessary background information is not in the question. Possible options include:

- Only query required columns instead of `*` to reduce transfer cost (and other performance benefits).
- Look at [**partitioning**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) and put practical time slices into separate tables. Add indexes to partitions as needed.
- If partitioning is not an option, another related but less intrusive technique would be to add one or more [**partial indexes**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).
  For example, if you mostly query the *current month*, you could create the following partial index:

  ```
    CREATE INDEX ticket_created_idx ON ticket(created)
    WHERE created >= '2012-12-01 00:00:00'::timestamp;
  ```

  `CREATE` a new index right *before* the start of a new month. You can easily automate the task with a cron job.
  Optionally `DROP` partial indexes for old months later.

  Keep the *total* index in addition for `CLUSTER` (which cannot operate on partial indexes). If old records never change, table partitioning would help this task a lot, since you only need to re-cluster newer partitions.
  Then again if records never change at all, you probably don't need `CLUSTER`.

#### Performance Basics

You may be missing one of the basics. All the usual performance advice applies:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization