# PostgreSQL delete query taking hours to execute

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I two tables table1 and table2 in postgresql-12:

`DELETE FROM table2 WHERE (ddate, itemno) NOT IN (SELECT ddate,itemno FROM table1);`

table1 has around 7000000 entries.
table2 has around 9500000 entries. Around 100000 matches are expected.
This command takes 5 hours to execute. How can I optimize this query?

Comment: It seems this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35007) on a similar question could help you.

Comment: Maybe it's already as optimised as it can be? Nobody can tell because you didn't bother to include the query plan. It's never going to be super-fast you have to scan at least one of the tables completely.

Comment: @RichardHuxton how do I search for the query plan? Please bear with me, I am new to postgresql

Comment: @JonasMetzler how do I convert this NOT IN part to IN part, as mentioned in the link?

Comment: Also, triggers are disabled for both the tables

Comment: OK, before you go any further google a bit around "postgresql query plan explain". There are two variants of that command you will want the plain EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Sourav Use LEFT JOIN with IS NULL as explained in the answer rather than NOT IN, put it in a CTE or subquery.

Comment: See [Best way to delete millions of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290900/best-way-to-delete-millions-of-rows-by-id/8290958#8290958)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question you need to provide more information about the tables or the query plan as @Richard Huxton just said, you can get the query plan by including `EXPLAIN` before any command you want to get its query plan, in your example it will be:

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM table2 WHERE (ddate, itemno) NOT IN (SELECT ddate,itemno FROM table1);
```

Do that and include it in the question, however if you didn't use indexes on your tables, you should try to do so, this may result in a significant speed up of the query. Check the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)