# Unable to use index in specific situations

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I am facing a strange and infuriating problem of my PostgreSQL 10 database not using indexes in specific situations. I have created an index of an md5 hash of one of the columns, and this index seems to work fine under normal circumstances:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM variants_table WHERE md5(variant_id) = md5('1_9746683_A_G');

QUERY PLAN
Index Scan using idx_variant_id_md5 on variants_table  (cost=0.71..50470.36 rows=12473 width=748)
   Index Cond: (md5(variant_id) = '00fa85f0ea97a4aa2898f838f427e560'::text)
(2 rows)
```

However, when I try to delete duplicates using this query:

```
EXPLAIN
WITH Ranked AS (
   SELECT
     md5(variant_id) as variant_id_md5,
     consscore,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY md5(variant_id) ORDER BY consscore DESC) as rn
   FROM
     variants_table
 )
DELETE FROM variants_table
WHERE (md5(variant_id), consscore) IN (
   SELECT variant_id_md5, consscore
   FROM Ranked
   WHERE rn > 1
 );

QUERY PLAN
 Delete on variants_table  (cost=3647060725.61..4520666023.49 rows=2949470436 width=70)
   CTE ranked
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=3096491910.93..3361944250.15 rows=11797881743 width=48)
           ->  Sort  (cost=3096491910.93..3125986615.29 rows=11797881743 width=40)
                 Sort Key: (md5(variants_table_1.variant_id)), variants_table_1.consscore DESC
                 ->  Seq Scan on variants_table variants_table_1  (cost=0.00..800237220.79 rows=11797881743 width=40)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=285116475.46..1158721773.34 rows=2949470436 width=70)
         Hash Cond: ((md5(variants_table.variant_id) = ranked.variant_id_md5) AND (variants_table.consscore = ranked.consscore))
         ->  Seq Scan on variants_table  (cost=0.00..770742516.43 rows=11797881743 width=46)
         ->  Hash  (cost=285115875.46..285115875.46 rows=40000 width=104)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=285115475.46..285115875.46 rows=40000 width=104)
                     Group Key: ranked.variant_id_md5, ranked.consscore
                     ->  CTE Scan on ranked  (cost=0.00..265452339.22 rows=3932627248 width=104)
                           Filter: (rn > 1)
(14 rows)
```

It defaults to a sequential scan.

I have tried everything to debug this including setting `enable_seqscan = off`, but no matter what, the query planner still uses the sequential scan, leading me to assume that it doesn't know how to use the indexes.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` for these statements, the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, and everything in plain text. By the way, version 10 is dead and buried, I would upgrade to a recent version asap. It might solve your problem as well.

Comment: Your first and your second query are also very different from each other, the only thing these have in common, it's that they use the same table. The outdated and unsupported version 10 can't optimize the CTE either.

Comment: I have upgraded to version 14 and ran the following: `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM variants_table WHERE md5(variant_id) = md5('1_9746683_A_G'); Index Scan using idx_variant_id_md5 on public.variants_table  (cost=0.71..50470.36 rows=12473 width=748) (actual time=0.051..0.062 rows=3 loops=1) Index Cond: (md5(variants_table.variant_id) = '00fa85f0ea97a4aa2898f838f427e560'::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=7
 Planning time: 0.309 ms
 Execution time: 0.163 ms
(6 rows)`

Comment: I can't run this on any of the other queries because EXPLAIN(ANALYZE) takes way to long

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The window function `row_number()` has to process the whole table, so it doesn't pay to use your index to begin with. Hence the query plan descends into a sequential scan.

#### Better query

[Postgres 15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/release-15.html#id-1.11.6.8.5.3.6) brought some optimizations for `row_number()`, and the upcoming [Postgres 16](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/release-16.html#RELEASE-16-PERFORMANCE) ships with more, but I am not sure how much your `DELETE` query can profit.

Be that as it may, this simpler query should perform better in any case:

```sql
DELETE FROM variants_table d
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM variants_table v
   WHERE  md5(v.variant_id) = md5(d.variant_id)
   AND    v.consscore > d.consscore
   );
```

Read:
*"Delete rows where another row with the same `md5(variant_id)` and a greater `consscore` exists in the same table!"*

If there can be complete duplicates on `(md5(variant_id), consscore)`, this query preserves all dupes with the highest `consscore` - unlike your original query. But your original query keeps an arbitrary winner, which is typically bad design, and you should really add a deterministic tiebreaker in this case - which you can use in my query accordingly.

If an arbitrary pick is good enough, you can use the system column `ctid` in a row-value comparison for this:

```sql
DELETE FROM variants_table d
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM variants_table v
   WHERE  md5(v.variant_id) = md5(d.variant_id)
   AND    (v.consscore, v.ctid) > (d.consscore, d.ctid)
   );
```

About row-value comparison:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

Note that my direct comparison works differently for `null` values than your original. Typically, you don't want to use my query if `variant_id` or `consscore` can be `null`. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

If `null` values can be involved, you'll have to define the desired behavior exactly.

If this is going to delete the majority of rows, other strategies may be more efficient. Like copying the few survivors into a pristine new table. See:

- [Best way to delete millions of rows by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290900/best-way-to-delete-millions-of-rows-by-id/8290958#8290958)

But I'd assume you are hunting for few duplicates. Consider making that expression index `UNIQUE` after you have cleaned up to prevent more dupes from creeping in. If possible.

#### Aside

Your query should be faster, yet, after optimizing that expression index with the data type `uuid` instead of text. See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684)

Or maybe a `bigint` hash is good enough? See:

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)

Comment: as always, a great in-depth answer